# Java Crash caused by existing native code

Tags: java, c++, c, dll, java-native-interface

I have a Java Swing Application interfacing with a third party shared library (DLL). The application crashes intermittently and when I inspect the crash dumps, i discover the crash occurred when attempting to access native code. See dump snippets below:

```
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd32321fdc, pid=7692, tid=8816

Stack: [0x0000000014b00000,0x0000000014c00000],  sp=0x0000000014bff2f0,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ftrScanAPI.dll+0x61fdc]
j  my.pkg.finger.futronic.FutronicScanner.close()Z+4
j  my.pkg.finger.ks.captureImage(Ljavax/swing/JLabel;Lcom/sf/sfxfinger/sfs;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;+25
j  my.pkg.sfxfinger.sfs.captureFingerImage(Ljavax/swing/JLabel;Lcom/sf/sfxfinger/sfs;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;+6
j  my.pkg.sc.laf.panels.FingerprintCaptureDialog$5.doInBackground()Ljava/lang/Object;+370
j  javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+14
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42
j  javax.swing.SwingWorker.run()V+4
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x1cf7f3]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.Futronic.ScanApiHelper.Scanner.CloseDevice()Z+0
j  my.pkg.finger.futronic.FutronicScanner.close()Z+4
j  my.pkg.finger.ks.captureImage(Ljavax/swing/JLabel;Lcom/sf/sfxfinger/sfs;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;+25
j  my.pkg.sfxfinger.sfs.captureFingerImage(Ljavax/swing/JLabel;Lcom/sf/sfxfinger/sfs;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;+6
j  my.pkg.sc.laf.panels.FingerprintCaptureDialog$5.doInBackground()Ljava/lang/Object;+370
j  javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+14
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42
j  javax.swing.SwingWorker.run()V+4
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Is it possible to catch the exception thrown by the native code in my Java code?

**NOTE:**
This library is a third party library which I do not have access to. Also, the crash behavior is very erratic. If it has to do with usage, my guess is that it will happen every time I try to use the device.

Comment: Note that you most likely are using the native library wrong.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen this behaviour is erratic, i make several interactions with the hardware device before the app crashes